# Adjust margins of grob object in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, gridextra, cowplot, grob

I made a grob object using the `cowplot` package. I'm adding `grid.lines()` and `grid.text()` objects to finished grob but as it comes out of cowplot it fills the whole page. How can I adjust the margins of the grob object to add some white space around the edges? Example code below.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2 ,nrow = 2,align="hv")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just use `theme(plot.margin = ...)` as you would in a ggplot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(cowplot)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p2 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
p3 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(disp, mpg)) + 
  geom_point()
p4 <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(qsec, mpg)) +
  geom_point()
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2 ,nrow = 2,align="hv")
```

[image]

```r
plot_grid(p1, p2, p3, p4, ncol = 2 ,nrow = 2,align="hv") + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(20,20,20,20), "points"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-04-29 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: You're a wizard. Much thanks. Didn't realize you can pass `ggplot` arguments to `plot_grid`.